# allocating a string inside a function inside a function in C

Tags: c, string, function

If i have a char *str=null before the call to func1 which takes it as argument and func1 calls another function (func2) that will also take this string as argument and allocate and change it.
should the signatures of the function be as follows?

```
   void func1(char ** str)
   void func2(char *** str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signatures don't have to have "nesting" argument types, unless you plan to alter the value of `str` as seen within the body of `func1`, as in:

```
void func1(char ** str) {
  func2(&str);
  assert(str == 0);
}
void func2(char *** str) {
  *str = 0;
}
```

Otherwise, `char ** str` is sufficient, although possibly still unnecessary:

```
void func1(char ** str) {
  func2(str);
}
void func2(char ** str) {
  *str = strdup("");
}
int main() {
  char * str = NULL;
  func1(&str);
  assert(str != NULL);
  free(str);
}
```

Ideally, though, if `func2` always allocates a string, it should return it:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/cstr-alloc-32379663
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/// Returns a newly allocated "foo". The user must free it.
char* func2(void) {
  return strdup("foo");
}
```

Similarly, if `func1` always allocates the string, it should simply return it as well:

```
/// Returns a newly allocated "foobar". The user must free it.
char* func1(void) {
  char* str1 = func2();
  const char str2[] = "bar";
  char* str = malloc(strlen(str1) + sizeof(str2));
  strcat(strcpy(str, str1), str2);
  free str1;
  return(str);
}

int main() {
  char* str = func1();
  printf("%s\n", str);
  free(str);
}
```

Comment: Yea you are right, I don't plan on changing the string in func1, and I can return it in func2 but I want to do it for 3 arguments, maybe I can put them in a struct and just return it

Comment: @TamerMograbi Putting them in a struct might be the easiest way to do it, and it self-documents properly as well.

Answer (score 2):

The rule to remember is "if you are going to allocate directly in a called function, you must pass the **address** of the pointer to the function". (you can, of course, pass no parameter and just provide the return of `malloc` via the function return) Second, if you do **not** pass the address of the pointer as a parameter, you will have to return some value to assign to string in `main` as `str` is declared as a `NULL` pointer. (it is an empty pointer -- it itself has an address, but it points to nothing) Whether you return a `char *` type or a `void *` type is up to you. (they are both simply references to a memory address).

There are two primary means of allocating in a called function (1) providing the starting address for the allocated block of memory via a function return, or (2) passing the address to the pointer and allocating directly in the called function.

**Providing Allocation Address Through Return**

If you are going to utilize a return to provide the starting address to the newly allocated block of memory, there is no reason to pass anything to the functions. However, you must return a pointer to the start of the newly allocated block of memory. A simple example will help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ASIZE 16

void *func1 ();
void *func2 ();

int main (void) {

    char *str = NULL;

    str = func1 ();
    strncpy (str, "hello, world!", ASIZE);
    printf ("\n %s\n\n", str);

    free (str);

    return 0;
}

void *func1 ()
{
    return func2 ();
}

void *func2 ()
{
    char *p = malloc (ASIZE);

    if (!p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    return p;
}
```

**Direct Allocation Passing Address to the Pointer**

The next option available to you is to pass the **address** to the pointer you wish to allocate in the called function. Your function types can simply be `void` as you are not relying on a return.

The starting address to the new block of memory is directly assigned to the address of the pointer in the called function. It is available in `main` by virtue of the pointer being directly updated in the function. (this is why you must pass the **address** of the pointer, if you just pass the pointer itself, the function receives a **copy** of the pointer [stored at a different address] -- so there is no relation to the address of the pointer in `main`)

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ASIZE 16

void func1 (char **str);
void func2 (char **str);

int main (void) {

    char *str = NULL;

    func1 (&str);
    strncpy (str, "hello, world!", ASIZE);
    printf ("\n %s\n\n", str);

    free (str);

    return 0;
}

void func1 (char **str)
{
    func2 (str);
}

void func2 (char **str)
{
    if (!(*str = malloc (ASIZE))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

**Provide the Flexibility of Both**

You don't have to limit yourself to one method or the other. By smart coding, you can write your functions so they can be used to update the pointer directly **and** return the start address for new block for assignment as well. (note: size `sz` is passed as a parameter instead of using a `#define` in this example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *func1 (char **str, size_t sz);
void *func2 (char **str, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    char *str1 = NULL;
    char *str2 = NULL;
    size_t sz = 16;

    func1 (&str1, sz);
    str2 = func1 (&str2, sz);

    strncpy (str1, "hello, world!", sz);
    strncpy (str2, "hello, Stack!", sz);

    printf ("\n %s\n", str1);
    printf (" %s\n\n", str2);

    free (str1);
    free (str2);

    return 0;
}

void *func1 (char **str, size_t sz)
{
    return func2 (str, sz);
}

void *func2 (char **str, size_t sz)
{
    if (!(*str = malloc (sz))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    return *str;
}
```

Of course all examples just print `hello, world!`. (and `hello Stack!` in this last example) **Note:** whether you pass `sz` as or parameter or by using a `#define` you must provide `malloc` (or `calloc`) the number of bytes to allocate. (it's up to you).

The important point is now to validate your memory use with a memory error checker such as `valgrind` or the like:

**Memory Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/layeredalloc
==28513== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28513== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28513== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28513== Command: ./bin/layeredalloc
==28513==

 hello, world!
 hello, Stack!

==28513==
==28513== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28513==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28513==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==28513==
==28513== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28513==
==28513== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28513== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

By using `valgrind` you can insure all memory allocated was in fact freed, and more importantly your use of memory was correct:

```
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts
```

Comment: "if you are going to allocate in a called function, you must pass the address of the pointer to the function" - but only if you're dead set on *optionally* modifying some existing pointer when you do so, right? Otherwise, why not simply return the pointer, like `malloc`, `strdup`, etc. do?

Comment: Your statement is true. I was answering the question posed by the OP's desire to pass either by `char **str` or `char ***str`. In the absence of any parameter, then simply returning the return of `malloc` etc.. is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

I clearly didn't understand your question at first, but if what are you trying to do is this call a function on null pointer and then send it to another function that allocates memory for the pointer and then using the pointer on main, then yes, your signatures are fine.
Code example:

```
void f(char** p){g(&p);}
void g(char*** q){**q = malloc(4); strcpy(**q,"abc");}
int main(){
  char * p = 0;
  f(&p);
  printf("%s",p);
  return 0;
}
```

This isn't the best code but it will do the work

Comment: planning to use malloc since the str is equal to null before the function

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you shouldn't need to pass the string by reference to the second function because it's already a reference to the pointer you want to modify. See the example below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func2(char **str)
{
    /* allocate the string and populate it. It can be populated from func1 or main as well,
       provided this was called first to allocate the string. */
    *str = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*str, "Hello, World!");
}

void func1(char **str)
{
    /* other stuff presumably */

    /* allocate some data to the string. no need to pass this by reference, 
       we already have the address of the pointer we want to modify. */
    func2(str);

    /* more stuff presumably */
}

int main()
{
    char *str = NULL;

    /* Need to allocate data and store the location in the variable 'str'.
       Pass by reference so func1/func2 can modify the value (memory address)
       stored in the 'str' variable. */
    func1(&str);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work but it's not the best way. You can do something like this:

```
int main(){
    char *str = null;
    func1(&str); // There you are passing the address of the pointer to the first char in the string
}

void func1(char** str){
    func2(str); // In this function str is a pointer to the address of the pointer to the string, so passing it the other function will can modify the string
}

void func2(char** str){
// some code
}
```